# XmlSerializer.Deserialize ignore unnecessary elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-deserialization

I have used xsd.exe to generate .cs file from my XML response.

In my XML response there are few elements which are not required in app, I want to omit those, so I removed them from response xml file and regenerated the .cs file.

I use this .cs file to deserialize from my xml server response (which has those unnecessary elements), which causes System.InvalidOperationException.

Please let me know how can I parse or deserialize the server response to the class which has only those properties which are required.

I wok for Windows Phone app.

Thanks,
Kavit.

Answer (score 1):

Try decorating the properties you no longer want with the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` attribute.

> By default, all public fields and public read/write properties are
>   serialized by the XmlSerializer. That is, the value of each public
>   field or property is persisted as an XML element or XML attribute in
>   an XML-document instance.
>
> To override the default serialization of a field or property, create
>   an XmlAttributes object, and set its XmlIgnore property to true. Add
>   the object to an XmlAttributeOverrides object and specify the type of
>   the object that contains the field or property to ignore, and the name
>   of the field or property to ignore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

Comment: Hi Gusdor, Thanks for the quick reply, what you mentioned I think that is required for serialization, actually I have to deserialize the server response, so I want to create a class file with properties which are actual useful in my app, and want to deserialize only those attributes, ignoring rest.

Comment: @patelkavit Simply remove the properties that you don't need. XmlIgnore works for both. It is a nice way of having a public property but omitting it from any (de)serialization. For any more details you are going to need to post some example code to work from.

Comment: Yes that works, but tends to unnecessary messy code :(, actually in webservice response there are 70 XML elements out of those we need only 10-12 in our app. Thus, We wanted to create a class with only those 10-12 properties which make class more readable.

Comment: @patelkavit When a class is deserialized, it will only fail if there are no matching elements or attributes for public properties or fields marked as XmlAttribute or XmlElement. Create a class with only the properties you wish to deserialize and it will work with a nice tidy class. However, if you then serialize this class, the output may fail to validate with the schema if the properties you ommited are required.